# Identify Schema for table depending on User Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a scenario where there are two database 
schemas: Schema1 and Schema2 and a table: Table1.

Same Table1 exisits in both the schemas like Schema1.Table1 and Schema2.Table1.

Now we have some stored procedures which will be in another Schema say Schema3.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SCHEMA3.GETDETAILS ( 
          @AS_CODE_TYPE VARCHAR(1) , 
          @AS_OUT_FIELD1 VARCHAR(50) OUT ,
         @AS_RETURN_VAL INTEGER OUT 
                  ) 
AS
BEGIN 

    SELECT @AS_OUT_FIELD1 = [EXTERNALREFKEY] FROM TABLE1 WHERE CODE_TYPE = @AS_CODE_TYPE 

    IF @AS_OUT_FIELD1 <> ' ' 
    BEGIN 
        SET @AS_RETURN_VAL = 1 ; 
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        SET @AS_RETURN_VAL = - 1 ; 
    END   
END
```

Now My question:

How do i get the schema details for a given user .

Do i need to modify the SP to dynamically append the schema to table depending on the user access to a specific schema.

Please help

Comment: This sounds like a very sloppy design and one that is going to suffer performance problems down the road. When you don't specify the schema it will first look to use the current users default schema and then dbo.

Comment: This is basically a migration requirement from legacy AS400 DB2 to Sql DB and in DB2 it has around 40 different schema and all the SP were deployed in another schema, just trying to recreate the same in new environment

Comment: Yikes. Just because you always did something a certain way doesn't mean you have to continue that. You would have to make sure the default schema for every user is correct one so that your procedures will pull from the correct table. If at all possible I would consider making this less complicated. I am guessing maybe the schemas here are used to segregate sets of data in a multi-tenant database architecture?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a user, if you don't specify it's schema, it will has the default schema '`dbo`'.

You can get the user schema by running the bellow query in `master` DB:

```
USE master;
SELECT s.name user, s.default_schema_name user_schema FROM sys.database_principals s 
WHERE s.name='user'
GO
```

For example:

[image]

You also can alter the user schema if you have the permission.

For more details, [Changing the default schema of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-changing-the-default-schema-of-a-user):

```
ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;  
GO
```

Hope this helps